# Where to get the DOS version of "DataTalk" (for Aladin diving computers)?

Tags: hardware, dos

In order to configure my Aladin diving computer, I built the interface as described [here](http://www.muenster.de/~matthias/aladin/building.htm).
The software "DataTalk" can be used to configure the diving computer. However, the Windows version (which can be downloaded [on the manufacturer's website](http://www.scubapro.com/en-GB/FRA/product-support.aspx?subject=manuals) together with "DataTrak") only works with an original "MemoMouse" – which is quite expensive for just using it once (for configuration).

The DOS version of DataTalk seems to work with the self-built interface. However, all the links I find are outdated since about 2006 or 2009.

There are alternatives for *reading* from the diving computer, like [WLog](http://www.wlog.de), but I did not find any for *configuring* it.
Do you know an alternative that runs on windows or linux? (If not, do you know where you can still get the DOS version?)

*Note:* asked this on [outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/8887/5601) before, but got "redirected" here in a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here, too, because you don’t ask for software recommendations (see related Meta discussion [Is asking for the canonical location of source code on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1220/60)). ··· I don’t know this domain, but if it’s possible that there could be other suitable tools, you could rephrase your question to ask for a recommendation (and a possible answer might recommend the DOS version of DataTalk, possibly with a link/hint how to get it).

Comment: Search for terms like 'abandonware' (or just "old software") to find websites with old software.

Comment: @unor I rephrased it. Actually, this is even closer to what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.scubadiving.com/gear/accessories/dcpc-interfaces

> The DataTrak download system includes a unique piece of hardware
>   called the "Memo Mouse." It's not a mouse in the conventional computer
>   sense; it's a memory device between the dive computer and the personal
>   computer. What's it for? The Aladin dive computers store only 200
>   minutes of dive time in fully detailed form--say, four dives. After
>   that, the newest dive starts overwriting the oldest. But if you take
>   the Memo Mouse on your dive trip, you can download to it and store up
>   to 66 hours of dives--and leave your laptop at home. When you get
>   home, you download from the Memo Mouse to your laptop

So, I am not sure that you are looking for a **software** recommendation. You probable want to buy a cheep one, or make one yourself.

I presume that you also asked around, and posted on local diving forums, asking for a loan of one?

There is [currently one on eBay](http://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_nkw=uwatec%20memo%20mouse) for Eur 69, which seems a bit stiff (although cheaper than the original cost of [$300](http://www.michaelmcfadyenscuba.info/viewpage.php?page_id=66)).

Since you are handy, maybe you can get the plans and build your own? Also, try asking at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ if anyone knows how.

From http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.plongeur.com/forums/showthread.php%3Ft%3D16100&prev=search  (translated by Google from French to English)

> Yes there is a "free" project MemoMouse clone. it's here: ***[You must
>   register to see links.]*** But it takes some work.

Below that, someone else says

```
 Indeed, € 20 is more than interesting stuff ... but I'm not at all electronicien

Is there someone on the forum capable of mounting this kind of device?
```

Again, there is a link, which presumably tells you how to build a MemoMouse clone for Eur 20, but, again, you need to register to see it.

There seems to be a [solution using a Palm Pilot](http://www.michaelmcfadyenscuba.info/viewpage.php?page_id=66) (you might get luck & pick up an old one cheaply on eBay).

The same page says that "A Web Site has details of how to build your own mouse. If you are handy with electronics, I am sure that you could build one very easily and cheaply" - but, alas, the plans are no longer there. Perhaps you could contact the owner of http://nuro.republika.pl/genie/indexe.htm ?  Or email the guy who posted the plans to build the interface - he *might*know.